# “ Infinite shrinkage found in 'page'.” in AGU template in LaTeX?

Tags: templates, geometry

The [AGU](https://www.agu.org/publish-with-agu/publish#1) provide us the template for submitting papers, in which, there are a `si_template_2019.tex` for supporting information within the [file](https://www.agu.org/-/media/files/publications/august-2022-latex-templates.zip?la=en&hash=9e4faa60fb79fd5ff3e1ce97013863f8). But, when run it, we can get an error

```
! LaTeX mark Error: Infinite shrinkage found in 'page'.
```

It is a little weird as I haven't change anything in it but get an error. How to repair it? Why do so many journals provide the templates with wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a commercially supported class from the publisher, so they should fix it but this removes the infinite shrink (it comments out `\vss` and repaces by a skip with finite shrink)

```
\documentclass[draft,jgrga]{agutexSI2019}

% sigh
\makeatletter
\def\@makecol{\setbox\@outputbox
     \vbox{\boxmaxdepth \maxdepth
\ifdim\ht\dbltopins<1pt\else\unvbox\dbltopins\fi
     \unvbox\@cclv
\ifdim\ht\dblbotins<1pt\else\unvbox\dblbotins\fi%
\ifvoid\footins\else\vskip\skip\footins\footnoterule\unvbox\footins\fi
%\vss
\vskip 0pt plus 1fil minus \maxdimen
}%
%\global\savefigandtabnumber\figandtabnumber
%\global\advance\savefigandtabnumber by 1 %% Because loop stops one short
                                         %% of the total number of figs
\global\savedblfigandtabnumber\dblfigandtabnumber
   \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}\gdef\@midlist{}\@combinefloats
   \setbox\@outputbox\vbox to\@colht{\boxmaxdepth\maxdepth
   \@texttop\dimen128=\dp\@outputbox\unvbox\@outputbox
   \vskip-\dimen128\@textbottom}%
   \global\maxdepth\@maxdepth}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I really don't know how these commercial companies can still make money. Regarding this technical problem, I sent them an email, but no solution was found for a week. Real technology must be pursued by those who really love it.

Comment: David, in my experience reading instructions provided by reputable print-on-demand suppliers, I have seen (in the same documentation, not TeX): (a) Every page must have a number; plus (b) Do not number these pages (list). I have also seen (c) Your PDF must not have metadata. I am sure that the system works, only because folks do not read the instructions.