# AGU Template supporting information issue

Tags: agutex

The supporting information file just gives infinite shrinkage error for the AGU journal template. I have emailed them and tagged them on twitter regarding this but there is no reply. Did anyone manage to work it out?

Cheers.

Comment: put a bit more effort in your question. Do not expect others to hunt down the internet to find the template and the "supporting information file" you used and to try to figure out which error you get. Add a link, show a complete example here and show also your log-file.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703682/36296